# Wich NIC is going out to the Internet when I have a Linux box with two NICs and they are in the same subnet?

Tags: linux, networking

When a Linux box has two NICs, both connected to the same subnet, is there any way to tell which one is being used as the default gateway?

Comment: The one with the default gateway. Regardless, this is hardly a question that fits the profile of the site.

Comment: Seems I cant downvote myself. but "ip route ls" will do what you actually asked. I thought your question was actually interface/ip selection behaviour when speaking on the same subnet. I guess the answer can just stay for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of conditions.

- Both IP addresses are on the same subnet (like you already mentioned)
- The socket being generated has not been bound specifically to a particular source IP programatically.
- There are no advanced routing rules that switch behaviours based off of various other conditions (fwmark, dsmark etc).
- The destination is to the same subnet.

In this case, the routing table is queried, so in my example, I have two IPs on the same subnet

```
# ip addr ls | grep inet
    inet 192.168.122.224/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.122.160/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global eth1
```

Which one to choose? Well the answer to this is dominated by the routes. So if we check that out..

```
192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.224 
192.168.122.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.160
```

Of course, if I have a default route for a destination that will be where I would go and it would be quite obvious. Normally the same routing table wont accept duplicate rules for destination networks.

The `src` field indicates which IP address to select for that subnet. But, hang on -- theres a problem here. I have two routes, one for each device both specifying the source! What to do?

Other factors in the route might weigh one over the other, the `metric` or `preference` for example.

Well, simply put if all else fails and both rules are equal the kernel just chooses the one that is first in the list. If you have a preference, then you choose that one.

If you want to make a preference, you'll need to add rules (such as in my case) to the route like this:

```
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.122.224 metric 2
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.122.160 metric 1
```

Which will alter the routing rules out of the host. You might need to clear your arp cache after doing that.